# How to avoid warning "GC Warning: Limiting number of mark threads"

Tags: linux, mono, warnings

I am working on linux and getting warning "GC Warning: Limiting number of mark threads" on running my binary. On using Google, I find it is something faced by others also, but I could find a way to stop this warning. Can you please tell a way out. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-bugs/2010-August/103261.html

> The warning is harmless, if you don't want to see it, define the env
>   var GC_MARKERS to a value like 4.